# Rewrite rules in .htaccess never take effect and no redirects ever happen

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache2, vps

I recently set up a vps with digital ocean to let my site run on php7 and http2
Everything is running great but my sites .htaccess file is not redirecting as it should. I have changed up my 000-default.conf and my apache2.conf files to allow .htaccess to work!

This is what I have in my .htaccess file

```
#ExpiresActive On
#ExpiresByType image/gif "now plus 9 years"
#ExpiresByType image/png "now plus 9 years"
#ExpiresByType image/jpeg "now plus 9 years"
#ExpiresByType image/x-icon "now plus 9 years"

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://example.com [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewiteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

On my other shared hosting this file worked fine and I know this file is working because if I uncomment all of the ExpiresByType it breaks my site so I will probably take those out!
Also the index.php does not redirect. Have I missed something somewhere?

Have been told that my question is unclear so will provide my sites .conf file.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<LocationMatch "^(.*\.php)$">
    ProxyPass fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/example.com/public_html
</LocationMatch>
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    AccessFileName .htaccess
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem"

    Protocols h2 http/1.1
    H2Direct on
    ServerAdmin phillip@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I can also confirm that sudo a2enmod rewrite is enabled. Hope this clears things up.

Comment: Sorry but as it stands the question is currently considered unclear because of the lack of information provided. In order for our community to provide a solid answer please provide the conf from within `/sites-enabled/` and details if you have or not enabled mod_write using `sudo a2enmod rewrite`.

Comment: NP Will do Simon, will edit my question now

Comment: All done @SimonHayter hope this helps

Comment: You don't actually state what is "not redirecting _properly_" (apart from the "Also index.php..." part). So, it is redirecting, but not as expected? Can you include what URL(s) you are requesting and what output you are expecting and what output you are currently getting.

Comment: ah no problem @w3dk I am expecting all versions to redirect to https://www.example.com presently if i goto example.com or example.com or http://example.com it stays there so naturally I want them all to goto https://www.example.com. Hope this helps?

Comment: So, you're saying _nothing redirects_? (The redirects you have are not necessarily correct since they redirect everything to the document root, but if they work as intended elsewhere then OK.) Do you get redirected if you try something even more basic, such as: `RewriteRule ^ http://example.com [R,L]` (literally `example.com`). That should go _before_ your existing directives. Is this .htaccess file in the document root? Do you have any other .htaccess files?

Comment: (Use inline code `backticks` for your URLs, otherwise they get auto-formatted and we can't understand them.)

Comment: Yep thats exactly what I am saying and I just modified my htaccess file with a really simple redirect as you suggested above and no it's still not redirecting! Yes that is my only .htaccess file and it is in the root of my website.

Comment: This is what I have now `Options +FollowSymLinks RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]` and no not workig as expected, I did make a small typo in that code above and it did break my site for a second.

Comment: "not working as expected" implies it's doing _something_, but not as expected. But what you mean is that it's not doing _anything_ - correct? You could just try `Redirect /temp http://example.com` (mod_alias redirect) and access `/temp` in your browser - are you redirected? (`example.com` being an external domain.)

Comment: Hi @w3dk nope not at all! naturally it's doing something as when i leave a typo in my htaccess it still breaks the site! Some weirdness is happening hey?

Comment: I mean the "RewriteRule redirect" is doing nothing. Did you try the `Redirect`?

Comment: Yep have tried that @w3dk and still no redirect!

Comment: Sometimes you need to enable `ModRewrite` in `httpd.conf` file by removing the `#` symbol in front of it.

Comment: Hi @knif3r I enabled mod rewite using sudo a2enmod rewite. httpd.conf is in the mods_available but I believe I got everything setup in apache2.conf correctly

Comment: just checked again after sudo a2enmod rewite and I got rewite module already enabled. 
In my sites conf file I have AllowOveride all as you can see above!

Comment: Also sometimes you need to enable it in `php.ini`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out and it was really simple. Instead of modifying my sites virtual hosts I file modified my apache2.conf file located at /etc/apache2/apache2.conf as such

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Took me a while to get there but simple when you know how! Thanks for all your help

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However, you shouldn't have to put these directives directly in `apache2.conf` - which controls your entire server. You've used `Require all` here, which suggests you're on Apache 2.4, whereas in your question you used the Apache 2.2 `Order` / `Allow` directives - this could have perhaps indicated a conflict?

Comment: Ah yea, Thanks for that @w3dk for that! I just added sendmail to my vps as well and thats not working so it probaly already has caused a conflict